# Is there a way I can place text after an <h1> on the same line?

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<h1><span>Test Heading</span></h1>
```

and CSS:

```
h1 { font-size: 1.3em; font-family: calibri, arial;border-bottom: 1px solid #999; padding-bottom: 10px;margin-bottom: 5px; background-color: pink;}
h1 span { color: #fff; background-color: #446688;padding: 1px 5px 3px 5px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; }
```

Right now it displays something like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
x Test Heading X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I need to be able to do is have text appear to the right of the heading like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     Some text aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
x Test Heading X     more text aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I think this is not so easy to do. Can anyone suggest how I could do this? I guess I need some kind of outer enclosing DIV for my heading but when I tried that the text always appears below the heading instead of to the right.

Here is an example of what I have now

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ryGFq/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap it all in a `<div>`, move the pink background color and bottom border to the `<div>`, and float the `<h1>` to the left.

For example:

```
<div class="bb">
    <h1><span>Test Heading</span></h1> 
    This is text that I want to make appear to the right of the heading and above the blue base line. This is text that I want to make appear to the right of the heading and above the blue base line.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bb {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: pink;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: calibri, arial;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
}
h1 span {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #446688;
    padding: 1px 5px 3px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FNLBD/

You'll probably want to pretty up the paddings and margins a bit though.

Answer (score 2):

Put the H1 text and the other text in separate DIV's. Then make them float next to one another using CSS

Comment: I wouldn't... Either use `display: inline` or, if you want to be able to set dimensions, use `display: inline-block` (along with IE-centric hacks).

Comment: This doesn't work as I want to still retain the line at the bottom of the header. The one I marked with hyphens above If I do this the line just extends below the heading.

Answer (score 2):

[Float](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/) the heading.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
display:inline;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gKqQc/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the H1 CSS:

```
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
```

This will float your heading left so that the text can wrap around it on the right, Check [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryGFq/1/), The Margin-right will add a 10px margin to the right of the heading for presentation.

Comment: This looks pretty good. But my original has a blue line that extends from one side of the page to the other. The line is the bottom border of the heading. Is there a way that I could simulate that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ryGFq/4/ I dont understand exactly what you want, do you want the text inside the pink box? which then can have a blue line across the bottom, otherwise this wont be possible, and you will have to create another div under these ones, and style that.

Answer (score 0):

`float`-ing the `h1` to the `left` is the best option in this case and your markup could do with a little tweaking to accomplish this in the best possible way.

```
<div class="box">
    <h1>Test Heading</h1>
    <p>This is text that I want to make appear to the right
       of the heading and above the blue base line. This is
       text that I want to make appear to the right of the
       heading and above the blue base line.</p>
</div>
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/ryGFq/10](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/ryGFq/10/)**

You'll see there's a second option in the demo too showing the best way to have the content left justified, however an absolute value is required for the `margin-left`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
display: table-cell;
```

For both the H1 and the Text. They will appear next to each other.